# How to extract value from pyspark.sql.function?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using some pyspark.sql.functions:

```
print(ratings.select(mean('rating')).take(1))
print(ratings.select(stddev('rating')).take(1))
```

The output is:

```
[Row(avg(rating)=3.581564453029317)]
[Row(stddev_samp(rating,0,0)=1.1171018453732544)]
```

How can I extract the value so that I can assign it to a variable, e.g.

```
mean_ratings = ratings.select(mean('rating'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take returns a list of Rows. Index into the list to get the first row, then pull out the field you are looking for:

```
mean_ratings = ratings.select(mean('rating')).take(1)[0]['avg(rating)']
```

Comment: Thanks David.  I thought about doing something like this but it 'felt' a bit fragile, particularly the stddev version.

Comment: Yea, it's definitely hacky. You can also convert a row to a dict using `.asDict()`. They may feel more comfortable/stable to use, especially in situations where you have more than one key in your Row https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row.asDict